# python static method inheritance

Tags: python, polymorphism, static-methods

I read online in many places that static method most of the time isn't necessary, and we can just use top level function.
even on google style guide:

[image]

I'm using the following structure a lot and I can't find something equivalent, and I don't think is just unusual edge case.
sidenote: I'm not using the state of the class never on 'func_to_inforce_child_to_implement'.

```
fron abc import ABC


class SomeAbsClass(ABC):
      @staticmethod
      @abc.abstractmethod
      def func_to_inforce_child_to_implement()
         raise NotImplementedError()

class Child1(SomeAbsClass):
      @staticmethod
      def func_to_inforce_child_to_implement()
          # Some useful implementation


class Child2(SomeAbsClass):
      @staticmethod
      def func_to_inforce_child_to_implement()
          # Some useful implementation
```

and with this implementation way I can use polymorphism on those classes:

```
def polymorphism_on_class(classes: List[SomeAbsClass])
   for inherit_class in classes:
       inherit_class.func_to_inforce_child_to_implement()
```

Comment: `class` is a key word in python, cannot be used as variable name.

Comment: this method `func_to_inforce_child_to_implement` should be a `abstract` method not `static`

Comment: right, thanks, missing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out on the beauty of abstract base classes in Python, the `abstractmethod` decorator.  A subclass that does not implement the abstract method will generate a runtime error when instantiated:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class SomeAbsClass(ABC):
      @abstractmethod
      def func_to_inforce_child_to_implement(self):
         ...

class Child1(SomeAbsClass):
    def func_to_inforce_child_to_implement(self):
        # Some useful implementation
        ...

class Child2(SomeAbsClass):
    def some_other_func(self):
        ...

c1 = Child1()
c2 = Child2()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [42], line 19
     16         ...
     18 c1 = Child1()
---> 19 c2 = Child2()

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Child2 with abstract method func_to_inforce_child_to_implement
```